# Alternative to PDF stacks for Linux or Android

Tags: android, linux, pdf, pdf-viewer

[PDF Stacks](https://pdfstacks.com) is a program for browsing PDF files (not just viewing), but it is only available for Windows and Mac.

Is there any alternative for Linux or Android?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "browsing"?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/).

Like pdfstacks you can:

- Browse PDFs
- Organise PDFs
- Annotate PDFs

But unlike pdfstacks:

- Available for Windows, OS-X, **Linux, iOS & Andoroid**
- Also available as browser plug-in
- Free basic packages (2GB of storeage)
- Cross Platform Sync
- Reference & Citation Manager
- Groups & Collaboration tools *Limited on the free plan*

  - Invite others into public or private groups with shared papers, notes & annotations
  - Discussions within the group
- Social Networking and searching the public papers of other users

There are  different levels of usage plans:

- **Free Plan** £0 pa, **no credit card or billing details required**:

  - All of the above with 2 GB of storage
- **Personal Storage Plans**

  - **Plus** £44 pa = 5 GB Personal Library, 1 private or invite only group, 3 groups collaborators, 100 MB Shared Library
  - **Pro** £88 pa, As plus but 10 GB Personal Library
  - **Max** £132 pa, As Pro but Unlimited Personal Library starting with 100 GB.
- **Team Plans** *Various pricing based on the team size but with 50% discount for educational & non-profit use*

  - Unlimited private groups
  - Flexible team sizes *up to 50*
  - Unlimited group library space
- **Institutional Edition**

  - Some extra features and more support

*All prices quoted in Annually, (monthly x 11), in GBP and current as at 24/01/2016*

***N.B.*** I don't work for Mendeley but I do use it

Comment: I was not looking for such, but that indeed sounds very interesting (+1)! You might wish to add the sharing capabilities (reading lists/references/articles), citations and bibliography. Any word on the account needed? Any money involved? Privacy concerns? ;)