# Sharing paper reading log and comments between lab members

Tags: reading, academia

Members of an academic or industrial research lab read papers that may interest other lab members. The comments they have on papers may also be worth sharing with other members of the lab. I'm looking for a program or web application that could help organize a group reading so that each member know what other members have read as well as their comments.

A solution could be to use a simple Google Spreadsheet, e.g., with columns topic, reference to the paper, which lab member read it, what their main comments are, but I guess there may exist more efficient solutions.

Any desktop OS/browser/license/price is fine.

Comment: Should the papers and comments stay private, or are public solutions OK? I guess you don't want comments mixed with comments from the public though, right?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I'd prefer articles and comments to stay visible only to the lab members.

Comment: Android app OK for that? I've just stumbled upon a few of those recently. Not that I can post an answer with those (I've not even tried them). Take e.g. a look at [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/28234/185): *Mendeley* is available cross-platform. And then there's [ReadCube](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.readcube.mobile), able to import from several libraries.

Comment: @Izzy Good point, only desktop OS. I'll have a look at ReadCube! I am a very infrequent user of Mendeley, I'll dive a bit more to see whether it can accommodate my needs. The two main issues I have is, in a group, given a paper added in the group, 1) we can't see who added it (unless looking at the newsfeed) 2) we can't see the comments of another user. Or maybe it's possible but I don't know how to do it. I'll try and if unsuccessful ping webapps/SU.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities:

### Manubot

A git-based system to write scientific papers collaboratively, but which could also be used for gathering comments on specific papers. [See this publication for more details](https://greenelab.github.io/meta-review/).

### Hypothes.is

To cite [Hypothes.is](https://web.hypothes.is/)' "*How it works*"-section:

> **Select text to annotate**.
> Add tags and post publicly or save privately.
>
> **Reply to or share any annotation**.
> Link to notes or whole pages.
>
> **Annotate together in groups**.
> Collaborate privately with others.
>
> **Search your notes**.
> Explore all public annotations and profiles.